# Getting Undefined index: url from ajax result

Tags: php, ajax

*index.php*

```
<h1>Input the URL of the Video you want:</h1>
<input type="text" name="video" id="video">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<div id="showvideo"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#video').change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "youtube.php",
                date: {'url' : "$('#video').val()"},
                success: function(data){
                    $('#showvideo').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

*youtube.php*

```
if($_GET['url']){
    $url = $_GET['url'];
    $video = new Youtube($url);
    echo $video->getVideo();
}
```

When pass in urls,I get

> "Notice: Undefined index: url in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/youtube.php on line 41".

I followed the instructions from [this tutorial](http://iviewsource.com/codingtutorials/learning-how-to-use-jquery-ajax-with-php-video-tutorial/), it should be correct....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its `data` not date in your ajax

```
date: {'url' : "$('#video').val()"},
```

change this to

```
data: {'url' : $("#video").val()},
```

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
date: {'url' : "$('#video').val()"},
```

**with**

```
data: {url : $('#video').val()},
-------^^^---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--
```

Comment: @User016 ohhhh well thanks for showing me mistake corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
if(isset($_GET['url'])){
        $url = $_GET['url'];
        $video = new Youtube($url);
        echo $video->getVideo();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a two mistakes.

1. you have named the `data` attribute as `date`
2. You have enclosed the jquery object inside a string causing the object not to expand.

> data: {'url' : $('#video').val() }